# Reading a string from a form as a verbatim string, \\ showing instead of \

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, verbatim-string

I have the following property:

```
public string InstanceName
{
    get
    {
        return cbServerInstanceName.Text;
    }
}
```

where the input for

```
cbServerInstanceName.Text = "ServerName\ PcName"
```

This is showing up as

```
 "ServerName\\ PcName"
```

I tried using the string.replace but couldnt get it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Showing up where?

Comment: \\ is the escape sequence for \ backslash. So, that's how it is saved. What issue you facing?

Comment: is this the debugger ? this is normal

Comment: As im debugging. Im having issues connecting to my server and i figured that might be the issue. I may be mistaken though.

Comment: No that's no issue, that's how it is saved.

Comment: Balls, guess i need to continue hunting.

Comment: Thanks for ur help guys + someone post that as the answer, ill mark it as accepted once the 10mins is up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using C# and looking at strings in the debugger, it will escape certain characters and `\` is one of them; it will show in the debugger as `\\` but at runtime and not viewed in the debugger, it will be converted to a single `\`

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to take a stab at it and assume you're seeing `"ServerName\\ PcName"` using the debugger view in Visual Studio.  Since it is showing you `"a string\\"` instead of a `@"string literal\"`, you will see your slashes escaped. Just as you would with `"\r\n"` if you added a new-line.

If you can try printing your value to a MessageBox, or Debug or the Console. It *should* appear as you expect. *fingers crossed*